# Split columns by set of words and name columns with those words

Tags: r, stringr

My dataframe `df` contains multiple rows and a single column `x` like:

```
WordATextAWordBTextBWordCTextC
WordATextXWordBTextYWordCTextZ
```

I need it to be like:

```
WordA  | WordB  | WordC
TextA  | TextB  | Text C
TextX  | TextY  | Text Z
```

That is, first split the rows by "WordA", "WordB" and "WordC" and rename the columns accordingly.

I'm trying with:

```
data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$x),'WordA',fixed=TRUE)))
```

Is there an efficient way to handle this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you those words as 'WordA', 'WordB', etc in your original data. or is there any other patterns.  The reason I am asking is if this is the pattern, it could be easier, otherwise, have to check for other patterns

Comment: If this is the pattern, then `setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, str_extract_all(df$x, "Text.")), str_extract_all(df$x, "Word.")[[1]])`

Comment: WordA, WordB, WordC are just examples. Not necessaraly the real words

Comment: that is the reason why i asked,  If you can update with an example that mimics your original case, it would be easier.  Otherwise, people may come up with solutions based on this example and it may not work for you.